# What is the height of the Apple System Keyboard in iOS8/iOS8?

Tags: ios, xcode, uikeyboard

What is the height of the Apple System Keyboard in iOS 8 onwards with & without the predictive text bar which lies on top of the keyboard?

Comment: From memory, it's 384px without the text bar (and prob 40-44px for the text bar), but Anbu's answer below is a much better answer.

Comment: I just checked it out, its 224 points without the predictive text bar on iPhone 6 simulator and 253 points with the predictive text bar on iPhone 6 simulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
NSValue* keyboardFrame = [keyboardInfo valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey];
```

for detail value

Add an observer of `UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification` to the `viewDidLoad`;

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillChange:) name:UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification object:nil];
```

the delegate method

```
- (void)keyboardWillChange:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSDictionary* keyboardInfo = [notification userInfo];
    NSValue* keyboardFrame = [keyboardInfo valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey];
   NSLog("value ==%@",keyboardFrame);
}
```

Comment: do you know what the specific value would be? so I can provide this to the designer.